# how to pass command line properties to setup.exe

Tags: msbuild, wix

I want to pass parameters to msi when calling setup.exe as following :

```
setup.exe /l* log.txt EXEPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySetup\MyApplication.exe"
```

I have the following msbuild file :

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <exeD Condition="'$(EXEPATH)'!=''">$(EXEPATH.substring(0,$([MSBuild]::Add($(EXEPATH.lastIndexOf("\")),1))))</exeD>
        <exeFile Condition="'$(EXEPATH)'!=''">$(EXEPATH.substring($([MSBuild]::Add($(EXEPATH.lastIndexOf("\")),1))))</exeFile>

    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5" >
            <ProductName>Windows Installer 4.5</ProductName>
        </BootstrapperFile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Bootstrapper">
      <Message Text="$(exeD)"/>
      <Message Text="$(exeFile)"/>
      <Message Text="$(EXEPATH)"/>
      <Exec Command="msiexec /i MySetup.msi  /L log2.txt EXEDIR=&quot;$(exeD)&quot; EXEFILENAME=&quot;$(exeFile)&quot;" Condition="'$(EXEPATH)'!=''" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

As you can see I calculate two variables exeFile and exeD which I'll use in the Exec command which are supposed to be passed then  to MSI file which wix file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MySetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Sofiane" UpgradeCode="c151e7ab-b83a-445f-93b2-2ab7122ea34b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Property Id="EXEDIR" Secure="yes" Value="{}"/>
    <Property Id="EXEFILENAME" Secure="yes" Value="{}"/>


    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MySetup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <Binary Id="InstallTools" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)InstallTools\bin\$(var.Configuration)\InstallTools.dll"/>
    <Binary Id="NotepadPlus" SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"/>
    <!--<CustomAction Id="OpenExe" BinaryKey="InstallTools" DllEntry="OpenExeUrl" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" Return="check" />-->
    <CustomAction Id="OpenExe" Return="ignore" Directory="exeDirectory"  ExeCommand="&quot;[EXEDIR]\[EXEFILENAME]&quot;" Impersonate="yes" Execute="deferred"/>
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="OpenExe" Before='InstallFinalize'/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MySetup" />
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="exeDirectory" FileSource="@(EXEDIR)" />
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="myAppFile">
        <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
      <ComponentRef Id="myAppFile" />
      <!-- </Component> -->
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

What is strange is that when I test using, it works fine and the exe file is opened.

```
MSBuild.exe bootstrapper.msbuild /p:EXEPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySetup\MyApplication.exe"
```

The issue is that when I launch the setup.exe with the following command

```
setup.exe /l* log.txt EXEPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySetup\MyApplication.exe"
```

The EXEPATH parameter seems not be used or I don't know why ?

Any advice please ?

Comment: I don't see a question or problem in your post.  Try reviewing and editing, because I can't answer if I don't know what you're saying.

Comment: dear @jdlugosz I've edited my post. PLease check it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue by passing EXEPATH to MSI file and a custom action who will calculate EXEDIR and EXEFILENAME.

Here is the custom action :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace InstallTools
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult OpenExeUrl(Session session)
        {
            try
            {
                session.Log("Inside custom action");

                var expath = session["EXEPATH"];
                session.Log("EXEPATH ==> " + expath);

                var exedir =expath.Substring(0, expath.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
                session.Log("exedir ==> " + exedir);
                session["EXEDIR"] = exedir;

                var exefile = expath.Substring(expath.LastIndexOf("\\")+1);
                session.Log("exefile ==> " + exefile);
                session["EXEFILENAME"] = exefile;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var errorMessage = "Cannot open exe file ! Error message: " + e.Message;
                session.Log(errorMessage);
            }

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

The Wix file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MySetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Sofiane" UpgradeCode="c151e7ab-b83a-445f-93b2-2ab7122ea34b">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Property Id="EXEPATH" Secure="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MySetup" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
    <Binary Id="InstallTools" SourceFile="$(var.SolutionDir)InstallTools\bin\$(var.Configuration)\InstallTools.CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="SetupProps" BinaryKey="InstallTools" DllEntry="OpenExeUrl" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" Return="check" />
    <CustomAction Id="OpenExe" Return="ignore" Directory="exeDirectory"  ExeCommand="&quot;[EXEDIR]\[EXEFILENAME]&quot;" Impersonate="yes" Execute="deferred" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="SetupProps" Before="OpenExe"/>
      <Custom Action="OpenExe" Before="InstallFinalize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MySetup" />
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="exeDirectory" FileSource="@(EXEDIR)" />
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="myAppFile">
        <File Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetPath)" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentRef Id="myAppFile" />
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

and the msbuild script :

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>
        <BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5" >
            <ProductName>Windows Installer 4.5</ProductName>
        </BootstrapperFile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Bootstrapper">
      <Message Text="EXEPATH = $(EXEPATH)"/>
      <Exec Command="msiexec /i MySetup.msi  /L log2.txt" Condition="'$(EXEPATH)'!=''"  />
    </Target>
</Project>
```